# Validate Credit card without regExp

Tags: javascript

I am trying to validate credit card number which may contain four tests of alphanumeric characters, separated by hyphens (-) or without hyphens. Not using regExp.

I have tried different ways but I can't figure out how to do it properly.
That's what I have done so far:

```
    function isCredit(input) {
      var i, code;
      //if input.length > 19, stop execution
      if(input.length > 19) return false; 
      for(i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
       code = input.charCodeAt(i);

       //Matches to only numbers and Capital letters 
        if((code > 47 && code < 58) && (code > 64 && code < 91)) {

        //if every 5th character is "-"
          if((input.slice(4, 5) === "-") && (input.slice(9, 10) === "-") &&(input.slice(14, 15) === "-")) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
isCredit("12A4-56H8-43K6-36U3"); // returns true;
isCredit("4427A693CF324D14"); // returns true;
isCredit("----------------"); // returns false;
```

Any help and guidance appreciated!

Comment: Just let PayPal or Stripe do that kind of stuff for you.

Comment: Check if the string has any hyphens. If it has - check it's a set of digits with `-`, otherwise check it's only digits.

Comment: @PHPglue I think they are doing an assignment.

Comment: Yo, @PHPglue  I am novice to programming and to this site as well. Just asking guidance and help to tell me where I am going wrong. I am not  just putting a plain question to solve. Is that inappropriate ?

Comment: It's not entirely *validation*; to ensure a credit card is *valid* one must check with the card issuer, or attempt a transaction or something. There's no other way to determine whether the card has been cancelled or whatnot. It might be best to use the [Luhn algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm), by the way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly clear on your requirements. Here I'm assuming "12A556H8-43K636U3" is a valid card number if you allow hyphen omissions.

```
function isAlphaNum(ch) {
    var code = ch.charCodeAt(0);
    return ((code > 47 && code < 58) || (code > 64 && code < 91));
}

function isCard(str) {
    var char, i = 0, x = [1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1];
    while (char = str[i++]) {
      if (x[0] == undefined) {
        return false;
      }
      if (isAlphaNum(char)) {
        if (x[0]) {
            x.shift();
        } else {
            x.splice(0,2);
        }
      } else if (char == '-') {
        if (!x[0]) {
            x.shift();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
      } else {
        return false;
      }
   }
   return x[0] == undefined;
}
```

Comment: I suggest working out how you can address OPs confusion, and then perhaps working this (or something like this) into it...